# Split dataframe for chunk of dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Pandas` dataframe with dates column as `datetime` `objects`, *not strings*.

```
   Datetime               col1   col2

1  2021-05-19 05:05:00     3      7
2  ...
```

I would like to split it to multiple dataframes **by days**.

For example currently i split it by rows with a simple `num` var :

```
split  = range(0,len(data.index),num)
results = []
for c in split:
    results.append(data.iloc[c:(c+num)])
return results
```

How would I split it by days ? for example if `num = 10` create dataframes of *10 days* each, so first will have all rows with days 1-10, the second will have 10-20, etc. (not day of the month, but absolute groups of 10 days)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group DataFrame by date intervals using [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# test data
index = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-05-01')
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(len(index))}, index=index)

results = [part for _, part in data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10D'))]
```

The most important part is `pd.Grouper(freq='10D')`. It allows you to specify an interval for `.groupby()` ('10D' means '10 days').
In my case it works on index. You can specify the column name using `pd.Grouper(col_name, freq='10D')` or specify the level in the MultiIndex using `pd.Grouper(level=name, freq='10D')`.

When iterating through the GroupBy object, it returns a tuple `(name, group)`. List comprehension is used to remove the `name` from the iterable.

Check pd.Grouper [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) for the details.

Comment: thanks! how does the grouper knows you are doing this on the Datetime column?  you did not tell him on what column you talk about (  ? )

Comment: In my case it works on index. You can specify the column name using `pd.Grouper(col_name, freq=...)` or specify the level in the MultiIndex using `pd.Grouper(level=name, freq=...)`

Comment: thanks a lot, one more question, can you explain what this type of loop is ? : [part for _, part  , i never see this before and i don't know the name of this. how is it "part" is before the "for" ?

Comment: It called list comprehension. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

I would make a new column for date then group by the date

```
df['date'] = df['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: x.date()) # make date
dfs = [df[df['date'] == date] for date in df['date'].unique()] # group by date
```

now dfs is a dataframe split by dates

```py
dfs[0]
```

[image]

you can chunk them into 10

```
from functools import reduce
def chunks(L, n): return [L[x: x+n] for x in range(0, len(L), n)]
groups = chunks(dfs, 10) # 10 is number of dates to group
groupDfs = [reduce(lambda x,y: x.append(y), group) for group in groups]
```